# Unregister channel listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I have a list with twilio chat channels that the user is subscribed to. When a user clicks on one of these channels, the chat opens, messages are loaded, and the user subscribes to get new messages using `this.state.channel.on('messageAdded', message => { doSomething() })`

This all works great, but when the users selects a new channel, the listener for the old channel is still active. So when the user switches between channels and comes back to a channel that he already opened, he will receive messages twice (because I need to run `channel.on('messageAdded')` for every channel joined.

How can I unregister the channel.on('messageAdded') before switching to listen to an other channel?

Answer (score 1):

you can define some unique properties to separate your listeners. every time some user request you create the unique identifier and save in client local storage. and whenever you want to broadcast your messages first check the identifier of your message with client one then if they are equal show them